# React native tabnavigator icon

Tags: react-native, icons, react-navigation, tabnavigator

Good evening everyone!
I would like to change the color of the icon of the tabnavigator when you click on it, but I can not do it. Can you help me or give me another alternative?

```
 const Tabs = TabNavigator({
About : { screen : About },
Search : { screen  : Search },
Trois : { screen : Trois },
Quatre : { screen : Quatre }
```

},`{
   tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
  animationEnabled: true,
  tabBarOptions: {
  activeTintColor: 'green',
  inactiveTintColor: 'grey',
  showIcon: true,
  showLabel: false,
  style:{
    backgroundColor:'#FFF',
    borderTopWidth:1,
    borderColor:'#a2273c'
  }
  },
  })`

```
static navigationOptions = {
 tabBarIcon : ({tintColor}) =>{  

return <Image source={require('../icon/un.png')} style={{width:22,height:22,color:tintColor}} /> 

},
```

Answer (score 2):

You can change the `tintColor` of the image by supplying value to [`tintColor`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html#style) prop as mentioned.

> **tintColor**: [color](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/colors.html)
>
> Changes the color of all the **non-transparent pixels** to the **tintColor**.

```
tabBarIcon : ({tintColor}) => {
    return <Image source={require('../icon/un.png')} style={{width:22,height:22, tintColor}} />
}
```